# Prove that $f$ is the restriction to the unit disk of some entire function, given $f(2z)=2f(z)f'(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in the unit disk, and
$f(2z)=2f(z)f'(z)$ whenever $|z| < 1/2$.  Prove that $f$ is the restriction to the unit disk of some entire function.

Not sure how to attack this problem.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps try and prove there's a function which satisfies stated identity for all $z$ and agrees with $f$ on disk.

Comment: So $e^{1/2z}$ works.  But now what?

Answer (score 2):

Try to follow this chain:

1. $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $|z|<1$
2. $2f(z)f'(z)$ is holomorphic in $|z|<1$
3. $f(2z)$ extends to holomorphic function in $|z|<1$
4. $f(z)$ extends to holomorphic function in $|z|<2$

Rinse, wash, repeat...

Comment: The dish cycle as a metaphor for induction: Classy! I wonder if there's any non-inductive approach, but the specification of the problem doesn't really lend itself to anything else...

Comment: It's about shampooing, not washing dishes:  [Lather, rinse, repeat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lather,_rinse,_repeat)

Comment: Then why would you rinse before you wash?

Comment: Too tired to formulate instructions properly, I guess. Hope kingkongdonutguy will sort out the order.